# Sum of the series $\sum_{n \ge 0}{\frac{x^{4n+1}}{(4n+1)!}}$

Tags: power-series

I want to determine the sum of the series $$\sum_{n \ge 0}{\frac{x^{4n+1}}{(4n+1)!}}$$
I know this has to do with the sum
$$\sum_{n \ge 0}{\frac{x^{n}}{(n)!}}=e^x\;\; \forall x\in \mathbb R$$
But i can't see how to start. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610526) question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that 
$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots$$
and 
$$\sinh x=x+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots.$$
Add, divide by $2$.

If the $\sinh$ function is unfamiliar, replace it by the equivalent $\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$. Use the power series for $e^t$ to find the power series for $\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}$.