# How to find the sum of this power series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^{5n}} {(5n)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, exponential-function, roots-of-unity

How to prove that 
$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^{5n}} {(5n)!}=
\frac{2}{5} e^{-\cos \left( 1/5\,\pi  \right) x}\cos \left( \sin
 \left( 1/5\,\pi  \right) x \right) +\frac{2}{5}\, e^{\cos \left( 2/5\,
\pi  \right) x}\cos \left( \sin \left( 2/5\,\pi  \right) x \right) +\frac{1}{5} e^{x}?
 $$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of $\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(kn)!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1708900/sum-of-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac1kn)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. Clearly
$$
\frac{1}{5}\sum_{j=1}^5\mathrm{e}^{\omega^j x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{5n}}{(5n)!}
$$
where $\omega=\mathrm{e}^{2\pi i/5}$, since
$$
\sum_{j=1}^5 \omega^{jn}=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc} 5&\text{if}& 5\mid n, \\ 0&\text{if} &5\not\mid n. \end{array}\right.
$$
But 
$$
\omega=\cos (2\pi/5)+i\sin (2\pi/5), \,\,\omega^2=\cos (4\pi/5)+i\sin (4\pi/5), 
\,\,\omega^3=\overline{\omega^2},\,\,\omega^4=\overline{\omega},
$$
and so
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{5n}}{(5n)!}=\frac{1}{5}\sum_{j=1}^5\mathrm{e}^{\omega^j x}=\frac{1}{5}\left(\mathrm{e}^x+2\mathrm{e}^{x\cos(2\pi/5)}\cos\big(\sin(2\pi/5)\big)+2\mathrm{e}^{x\cos(4\pi/5)}\cos\big(\sin(4\pi/5)\big)\right).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Using the fact that $\omega$ the primitive fifth root of unity is such that
$$
5\cdot\mathbf 1_{5\mid n}=1+\omega^n+\omega^{-n}+\omega^{2n}+\omega^{-2n},
$$
and the fact that, since $\omega=\mathrm e^{2\mathrm i\pi/5}$, for every $k$,
$$
\omega^k+\omega^{-k}=2\cos(2k\pi/5).
$$

Answer (score 1):

In [a similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614986/17976), I described a method of solving through differential equations.  In this case, the series is the solution to the initial value problem 
$$y^{(5)}-y=0,y(0)=1,y'(0)=y''(0)=y'''(0)=y^{(4)}(0)=0$$