# Problems about Poisson distribution

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution

Let $p.r \in N$. Can one compute the sum of the following series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{{\lambda}^{p+rk}}{(p+rk)!}e^{-\lambda}?$

Comment: In which context does this arise?

Comment: See my answer to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610526) question.

Comment: Hint: Discrete Fourier transform.

Comment: Dear Lucian. Thank you very much.