# complex series exponential evaluation

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do we evaluate the series
$$\sum \frac{27^n}{(3n+1)!}$$
I could simplify this to 
$$\sum \frac{3^{3n}}{(3n+1)!}$$
but typically the tables provide you with the general series form of 
$$\sum \frac{x^{an+b}}{(an+b)!}$$
How do I go from herer? The b's are not the same!

Comment: See my answer to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610526) question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write the series as $$\frac{1}{3}\sum \frac{3^{3n+1}}{(3n+1)!}$$right?

Comment: hahah lol i guess youre right...

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$ where $\omega$ is a complex root of unity,

$$e^x=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{x^r}{r!}$$

$$e^{\omega x}=\cdots$$

$$e^{\omega^2 x}=\cdots$$

$$e^x+\omega^2\cdot e^{\omega x}+\omega\cdot e^{\omega^2 x}=?$$

Comment: could you lead me more where were going with this?

Answer (score 0):

Apply ratio test:
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{27}{(3n+4)(3n+3)(3n+2)}\right|<1$$
So series converges by ratio test.

Comment: This got downvoted in error. Could you do some editing so I can actually cancel my downvote and upvote it. Apologies

Comment: @Shailesh alright

Comment: Sorry it took time, but I canceled my downvote and upvoted it too.