# Find the sum of series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{kn}}{(kn)!}$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{kn}}{(kn)!}$$

Later edit:
Is this correct?

$$e^{z\epsilon_p} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n\epsilon_p^n}{n!}$$ 
$$\sum_{p=0}^{k-1}e^{z\epsilon_p} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}\sum_{p=0}^{k-1}\epsilon_p^n $$ 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{kn}}{(kn)!} = \frac{\sum_{p=0}^{k-1}e^{\epsilon_p^nz}}{k} $$

Comment: What does the series' index have to do with the series' term?

Comment: I am assuming you have to start from the exponential series somehow but I can't find the path.

Comment: Maybe there is $n$ instead $p$?

Comment: I messed up the indexes thinking of something else, sorry.

Comment: Hint: consider the sum $$\sum_\omega\exp(\omega z)$$ over every $k$th root $\omega$ of unity.

Comment: @Did Welcome back

Comment: A [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610526).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0} \frac{z^{kn}}{(kn)!}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{l=0}^{k-1} e^{\omega_{k}^lz}$$

where $\omega_k=\exp(2\pi i/k)$

It can be considered a generalization of $\cosh(z)$ function to multicomplex numbers (For $k=2$ the series is the $\cosh(z)$, for $k=3$ the series is called cosexponential function : $cx(z)=1+z^3/3!+z^6/6!+...$)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicomplex_number

http://books.google.it/books?id=vv_m6Dn3tM0C&lpg=PA19&ots=MrTDonAl7S&pg=PA19|Section&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: which is also a form of a [Mittag Leffler function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=mittag+leffler+function) or, almost like you said, a [generalized hyperbolic function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=generalized+hyperbolic+functions)