# Limits, Taylor expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find the limit: 
$$ 
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\displaystyle \sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty \frac{x^{in}}{(in)!}}{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty \frac{x^{jm}}{(jm)!}}
$$ 
for $n$, $m$ natural numbers.

It is easy to see that for elementary cases, like $n=0$ we just get the Taylor expansion for $e^x$. We get the limit equal to $1$ for $n=m$. Any idea how to find a general rule? Maybe we can use some sort of squeezing argument?

Comment: By $in!$ you mean $(in)!$, right?

Comment: I believe that [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610526) link might prove itself helpful.

Comment: Yeah, but I still can't find a general form for $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty \frac{x^{in}}{(in)!}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is $m/n$.  The reason is that

$$f(n,x) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{j n}}{(j n)!} = \frac1{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \exp{\left ( e^{i 2 \pi k/n} x\right )} $$

The sum is dominated by the $k=0$ term as $x \to \infty$.  The ratio of such terms is thus $m/n$.

**ADDENDUM**

Proof of the above assertion is straightforward.  The Taylor expansion of the RHS is

$$\frac1{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i 2 \pi j k/n} x^j}{j!} $$

Reverse order of summation (justified because each individual sum absolutely converges):

$$\frac1{n} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{e^{i 2 \pi j k/n} x^j}{j!} = \frac1{n} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{ x^j}{j!}  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{i 2 \pi j k/n}$$

The inner sum is a geometrical series, so the Taylor expansion is now

$$ \frac1{n} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{ x^j}{j!} \frac{e^{i 2 \pi  j} - 1}{e^{i 2 \pi  j/n} - 1} $$

It should be clear that the latter factor is equal to zero unless $j$ is equal to a multiple of $n$, where it is equal to $n$.  QED.

Comment: you put exp, so I think you don't need the $e$

Comment: @prometheus21: the two exponentials are required.

Comment: Yes I see that now

Comment: Very clever way to keep only the the $in^{th}$ terms !

Comment: @YvesDaoust: thanks.