# A curious power series

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to find a closed form for the following power series:
$$f(x;r) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{nr}}{\Gamma(nr)},$$
where $r$ is a positive integer. Until now, I've tried to let Mathematica compute it and I looked on the net but found nothing similar...
Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610526) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the idea of Alex.M, and exploiting the symmetry of the system of equations, we get closed expressions for the $c_k$. Indeed, the matrix involved in the system is a particular form of a Vandermonde matrix, which is a Discrete Fourier Transform matrix. This matrix is easily invertible and thus we get the $c_k$.

More precisely, we want to compute the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{nr}}{\Gamma(nr)} = x \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{nr-1}}{(nr-1)!}.$$
Then, let us define:
$$g(x;r) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{nr-1}}{(nr-1)!}, \quad f(x;r) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{nr}}{\Gamma(nr)} = x g(x;r).$$
We have then:
$$g(x;r) = \frac{x^{r-1}}{(r-1)!} + \frac{x^{2r-1}}{(2r-1)!}+ \dots $$
Then, we have:
$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial x^k} g(x;r) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{r-1-k}}{(r-1-k)!},\quad \forall k=1,\dots,r.$$
Then, in particular, we have:
$$g^{(r)}(x;r) = g(x;r). $$
The characteristic polynomial of this simple differential equation is then $z^r -1=0$. Let then $z$ be a primary root of $1$, that is, without loss of generality, $z = e^{\frac{ 2\pi i }{r}}.$
Then, the general  solution of the this differential equation is given by $\sum_{k=0}^{r-1} c_k e^{z^k}.$ For $k=0,\dots, r-2$, we have $g^{(k)}(0;r) = 0$ and $g^{(r-1)}(0,r) = 1.$
Then, identifying the terms, we have the following $r\times r$ system of equations:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
c_0 + c_1 + c_2 + \dots + c_{r-1} = 0 \\ 
c_0 + c_1 z + c_2 z^2 + \dots + c_{r-1} z^{r-1} = 0\\
\qquad \vdots \\
c_0 + c_1 z^{r-2} + c_2 (z^2)^{r-2} + \dots + c_{r-1}(z^{r-1})^{r-2} = 0\\
c_0 + c_1 z^{r-1} + c_2 (z^2)^{r-1} + \dots + c_{r-1}(z^{r-1})^{r-1} = 1.
\end{array}\right. ,
$$
or in matrix form, $\mathbf{F} \mathbf{c} = (0,\dots,0,1)$, where  $\mathbf{F}$ is the following matrix:
$$\mathbf{F} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1  & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
1 & z^1 & z^2 & \cdots & z^{r-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & z^{r-1} & (z^2)^{r-1}  & \dots & (z^{r-1})^{r-1}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and $\mathbf{c}=(c_0,c_1,\dots, c_{r-1})^t$. Since $z$ is a unitary root of the unity, this particular matrix is a discrete Fourier transform matrix. We will prove that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\mathbf{F}$ is unitary, that is:
$$ [\mathbf{F}]_k \cdot [\mathbf{F}]^*_l =  r \delta_{kl},$$
where $[\mathbf{F}]_k$ denote the $k-$th column of the matrix $\mathbf{F}$. Then, we have:
$$[\mathbf{F}]_k \cdot [\mathbf{F}]^*_l = \sum_{m=0}^{r-1} e^{\frac{2\pi i}{r} km } e^{\frac{2\pi i}{r} (-l)m } =  r \delta_{kl}. $$
Indeed, if $k=l$, the result is trivial. If $k\neq l$, we have:
$$\sum_{m=0}^{r-1} e^{\frac{2\pi i}{r} km } e^{\frac{2\pi i}{r} (-l)m } = \sum_{m=0}^{r-1} (e^{\frac{2\pi i}{r}(k-l)})^m = \frac{(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{r}(k-l)})^r - 1 }{e^{\frac{2\pi i}{r}(k-l)}- 1 } = 0,$$
since $(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{r}(k-l)})^r = 1$.
Then, we can write the inverse of $\mathbf{F}$ as:
$$\mathbf{F}^{-1} =   \frac{1}{r}\mathbf{F}^*
=\frac{1}{r} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1  & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
1 & \overline{z}^1 & \overline{z}^2 & \cdots & \overline{z}^{r-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & \overline{z}^{r-1} & (\overline{z}^2)^{r-1}  & \dots & (\overline{z}^{r-1})^{r-1}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then, we have:
$$[\mathbf{F}^{-1}]_r  =\frac{1}{r} \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ \overline{z}^{r-1}\\ \vdots \\  (\overline{z}^{(r-1)(r-1)}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then, we get:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
c_0\\ \vdots \\ c_{r-1} 
\end{pmatrix} = \mathbf{F}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ \vdots \\ 0\\ 1
\end{pmatrix} = [\mathbf{F}^{-1}]_r.
$$
Then, we can conclude:
$$c_k =\frac{1}{r} \overline{z}^{k(r-1)}, k=0,1,\dots, r-1.$$
We can finally conclude that
$$f(x;r) = x g(x;r) = \frac{x}{r}\sum_{k=0}^{r-1} \overline{z}^{k(r-1)}e^{z^k x}.$$
Most of this answer is due to the edit of Alex M., thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that $(\bar z)^{r-1} = (\bar z)^{-1} = z$, so the sum becomes $\sum \limits _{k=0} ^{r-1} z^k \Bbb e ^{z^k x}$.

Answer (score 2):

Except for the very first terms, it seems to me that there is no closed form.

What I obtained is $$f(x;1)=e^x x$$ $$f(x;2)=x \sinh (x)$$ $$f(x;3)=\frac{1}{3} e^{-x/2} x \left(e^{3 x/2}-2 \sin \left(\frac{1}{6} \left(3 \sqrt{3}
   x+\pi \right)\right)\right)$$ $$f(x;4)=-\frac{1}{2} x (\sin (x)-\sinh (x))$$ For $r>4$ appear generalized hypergeometric functions but some of them can simplify $$f(x;5)=\frac{1}{5} \left(e^x-\sqrt[5]{-1} e^{-\sqrt[5]{-1} x}+(-1)^{2/5} e^{(-1)^{2/5}
   x}-(-1)^{3/5} e^{-(-1)^{3/5} x}+(-1)^{4/5} e^{(-1)^{4/5} x}\right) x$$ $$f(x;6)=\frac{1}{3} x \left(\sinh (x)+\cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right) \sinh
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right) \cosh
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)$$ I give up with nightmares !

Comment: Sometimes taking a step back and avoiding computations reveals the hidden depth of a problem. Remeber Galois: ["Sauter à pieds joints sur ces calculs"](http://topo.math.u-psud.fr/~lcs/Galois/AbstnFR.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x,r) = x \sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty \frac {x^ {nr-1}} {(nr-1)!}$, for fixed $r \in \Bbb N \setminus \{0\}$ let $g(x) = \sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty \frac {x^ {nr-1}} {(nr-1)!}$. Convince yourself that after deriving $r$ times you get $g^{(r)} = g$. But this is an easy differential equation, as it has constant coefficients! If $\varepsilon$ is a primitive root of unity of order $r$, the general solution to your differential equation is $\sum \limits _{k=0} ^{r-1} c_k \space \Bbb e ^{\varepsilon ^k x}$. In order to find the coefficients $c_k$ note that for $0 \le k \le r-2$ you have $g^{(k)} (0) = 0$ and $g^{(r-1)} (0) = 1$. This means

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
c_0 + c_2 + \dots + c_{r-1} = 0 \\
c_0 + \varepsilon \space c_1 + \varepsilon ^2 \space c_2 + \dots + \varepsilon ^{r-1} \space c_{r-1} = 0 \\
c_0 + (\varepsilon ^2) \space c_1 + (\varepsilon ^2) ^2 \space c_2 + \dots + (\varepsilon ^2) ^{r-1} \space c_{r-1} = 0 \\
\dots \\
c_0 + (\varepsilon ^{r-2}) \space c_1 + (\varepsilon ^{r-2}) ^2 \space c_2 + \dots + (\varepsilon ^{r-2}) ^{r-1} \space c_{r-1} = 0 \\
c_0 + (\varepsilon ^{r-1}) \space c_1 + (\varepsilon ^{r-1}) ^2 \space c_2 + \dots + (\varepsilon ^{r-1}) ^{r-1} \space c_{r-1} = 1 .
\end{eqnarray*}$$

The determinant of this system is a particular form of a Vandermonde determinant easily seen to be nonzero, so the system has a unique solution. I do not know whether the minors associated to the unknowns are easily computable (they exhibit a lot of symmetry).

In any case, $f(x,r) = x \sum \limits _{k=0} ^{r-1} c_k \space \Bbb e ^{\varepsilon ^k x}$.

Comment: I thank you very much for this clever suggestion. Actually, I would have never thought to do a trick like that. It helped a lot.