# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(3n+8)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Determine whether or not this series converges or diverges $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(3n+8)!}$$

My attempt: I used the ratio test and ended up having 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(3n+11)(3n+10)(3n+9)(3n+8)}$$
which I then plugged in $\infty$ for $n$ and got $1/\infty$ which makes the limit $1$. Since the limit is less than $1$ the series converges according to the ratio test. Is this correct?

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610526) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(3n+11)(3n+10)(3n+9)} = 0 < 1$$

The limit of the above is $0$ since informally, as you've said $1/\infty = 0$. Take any small number and divide it by increasingly huger numbers on your calculator, you'll see the result approaching $0$. Since obviously $0 < 1$, the series converges by the ratio test.

Also, as Jack pointed out below, the $3n+8$ should not appear in the denominator, since $$\frac{(3n+11)!}{(3n+8)!}=(3n+11)(3n+10)(3n+9)$$

Comment: The $(3n+8)$ should not be there, $\frac{(3n+11)!}{(3n+8)!}=(3n+11)(3n+10)(3n+9)$. Anyway, that does not change much.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Woopsies, thanks for pointing that out, I edited my answer and credited you. :-)

Answer (score 4):

We can do more than prove convergence, we can compute it.

Let $\omega=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)$. Then:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!} = \frac{1}{3}\left(e^{x}+e^{\omega x}+e^{\omega^2 x}\right)\tag{1}$$
hence, by differentiating both sides:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{3n+2}}{(3n+2)!}= \frac{1}{3}\left(e^{x}+\omega\, e^{\omega x}+\omega^2\,e^{\omega^2 x}\right)\tag{2}$$
so, by evaluating at $x=1$:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(3n+2)!} = \frac{e}{3}-\frac{2}{3\sqrt{e}}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\tag{3}$$
then subtracting the first terms of the LHS:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(3n+8)!} = \color{red}{-\frac{20497}{40320}+\frac{e}{3}-\frac{2}{3\sqrt{e}}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}.\tag{4}$$

Comment: Indeed a very nice solution. But I did not understand, how did you get the first line?

Comment: @Nilan: from the discrete Fourier transform: $1^n+\omega^n+\omega^{2n}$ equals $3$ if $3\mid n$ and zero otherwise, so to consider $\frac{1}{3}\left(f(x)+f(\omega x)+f(\omega^2 x)\right)$ is equivalent to take every monomial of the Taylor series of $f$ in which the exponent is a multiple of three.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment. I'll study this myself. +1

Answer (score 1):

You are right.

You may also notice that
$$
(3n+8)!>n^2,\qquad n\geq1,
$$ giving
$$
0<\sum_1^{\infty}\frac1{(3n+8)!}<\sum_1^{\infty}\frac1{n^2}<+\infty
$$ and thus the **convergence of your initial series** by the **comparison test**.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do this one. See that 
$$
\sum \frac{1}{n!}
$$
is convergent isn't hard. Then note that
$$
\frac{1}{(3n+2)!} < \frac{1}{n!}
$$
and use the Comparison Test.