# How to evaluate $\sum \frac{1}{(3k)!}$?

Tags: real-analysis

How can I compute the limit of the following series :$ \sum \frac{1}{(3k)!} $?

Comment: What are your limits on the sum?

Comment: I would try considering $e^{x}+e^{ax}+e^{a^2x}$ for a suitable complex number $a$.

Comment: @RossMillikan per the hint from user Normal, it converges to $e + e^\zeta + e^{\zeta^2}$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive cube root of 1.

Comment: @hunter To one third of that.

Comment: much thanks for the hint !

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610526) question.

Comment: Look up multisection of series. Your problem is a multisection of $e^x$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider *decimation* of the series $f(z) = \sum_{k \ge 0} a_k z^k$. Call $\omega = \mathrm{e}^{\frac{2 \pi \mathrm{i}}{m}}$, a primitive $n$-th root of 1. It is easy to check that:

$\begin{align}
  \sum_{0 \le k < m} \omega^{r k}
    = \begin{cases}
        m & m \mid r \\
        0 & \text{otherwise}
      \end{cases}
\end{align}$

Thus:

$\begin{align}
   \sum_{0 \le r < m} f(z \omega^r)
     &= \sum_{0 \le r < m} \sum_{k \ge 0} a_k z^k \omega^{r k} \\
     &= \sum_{k \ge 0} a_k z^k \sum_{0 \le r < m} \omega^{r k} \\
     &= m \sum_{k \ge 0} a_{k m} z^{k m}
\end{align}$

Your series is nothing but:

$\begin{align}
   \frac{e^{\omega x}}{3}
\end{align}$

with $\omega = \mathrm{e}^{\frac{2 \pi \mathrm{i}}{3}}$